# What is going on in Kill List?

Tags: plot-explanation, kill-list

The British horror/thriller/mystery/I-have-no-real-idea-what-genre-fits movie [Kill List](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1788391/) was described by many critics as one of the best genre movies from the UK for ages.

It starts like a thriller drama and ends like some strange horror homage to The Wicker Man.

I'm confused about what is happening, especially near the end. Is there a reasonable explanation for why or how it ends the way it does or even: what the hell is happening?

Answer (score 5):

There's no clear explanation at all in the film but I felt that the conspiracy revolved around using the lead character (and his family) as an elaborate and semi-complicit human sacrifice (semi-complicit as the lead character chooses to carry out the previous assassinations that set up the storyline and is pressed into taking the job by his wife). Having said that, I think that the film is meant to be open to your own interpretation but hope that's useful. :)